# Creating custom map on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, overlay, openstreetmap

I am creating Map applications for both **Desktop**(C#) and **Android**. In some case I need to use **custom maps** for my applications and it should be able **cache** in the devices/PCs. I have already found  map engine (GMap.Net) for Desktop which is quite good (at least for me).

1). Are there any good engine for Android (preferably open source)?

2). Is there any way that I can use the same engines for both?

3).Any tools to create my own map(from our own bitmap images overlay
    onto the openstreetmap,google etc. to get the lat/lon and also for
    different zoom level. )

Comment: this may help: http://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=12473

Comment: @Phil Thanks, I am taking a look at it.